# Write a genetic method to remove a part of string after a particular character and till a particular character

Tags: java

I am trying to write a generic java method wherein I want to remove a part of a String after a particular character and till a particular character. For e.g. "My name is-A" is the String, then I want a method that should remove String till - or remove String after -. So my expected output here would be "My name is-" or "A". Below is my code.

```
String p="Free Float Factor-FFF";
        
        char[] s2= p.toCharArray();
        char[] s3;
        int i=0;
        do {
            s3=ArrayUtils.remove(s2, i);
            i++;
        }while((!s2.equals("-"))&&i<s2.length);
        
        System.out.println(new String(s3));

    }
```

The output I am getting here is **Free Float Factor-FF** I want either "Free Float Factor-" or "FFF" as the output. I am trying to convert the String into an array and then remove the part of the String till - but it is removing the last character. Slightly confused by this.

Comment: You mean that you want a function which returns two strings?

Comment: Yes. That will also work. I can tweak my logic in that manner.

Comment: How would you get "FFF" from "Free Float Factor-FF"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split("-")` operator on the `String` to the get the data like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p="Free Float Factor-FFF";
        String[] arr = p.split("-");
        System.out.println(arr[0] + "-");
        System.out.println(arr[1]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Free Float Factor-
FFF
```

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear how you would decide whether to return the bit before or the bit after. But you can get those two parts using `indexOf` to find the character, and then use `substring` to get the portion of the string:

```
int pos = p.indexOf('-');
String before = p.substring(0, pos);
String after = p.substring(pos+1);
```

Comment: The before part is meant to include the '-' (for whatever reason) so that should be `pos+1`